# How to process input in json format with multiple entry using node.js, express, and mongodb as API backend?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I want to process below json input (transferred throught REST API, using POST method) by using node.js, express, and mongodb as my API server.

{
   taskname: "task1"
   status: "ongoing"
   contributor: [
                   {
                       name: "andy",
                       role: "task owner"
                   },
                   {
                       name: "brian",
                       role: "executor"
                   }
                ],
   duedate: "2018-03-03"
}

What i know right now is from this tutorial (basic nodejs+express+mongodb) https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd

Could you show me how to solve this?

Thanks for your kind attention.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to `console.log` what you get from the request with `express.js`, 
You should install `body-parser` in order to get your request body,

To access post route, you need to define the route of the request and do something like this:

```
app.post('yourRoute', (req,res) => {
   console.log(req.body)
}
```

If you want to get a specific value from your request, for example get the `taskname` value from your json,
type something like this in your post route: `req.body.taskname`

You should initialize `express` of course like so: 
`var express = require('express'),
 app = express()`

Comment: Your answer is not relevant. What i ask is handling json input (mentioned in question).

Comment: So what do you want to do with that json?

Comment: It was already mentioned in OP. I mentioned again json data here. 

{ taskname: "task1" status: "ongoing" contributor: [ { name: "andy", role: "task owner" }, { name: "brian", role: "executor" } ], duedate: "2018-03-03" }

I want process this. e.g. store to mongodb.

Comment: var TaskSchema = new Schema({ taskname: { type: String }, status: { type: String }, duedate: { type: Date }});

var TaskContributorSchema = new Schema({ taskname: { type: String }, name: { type: String }, role: { type: String } });

// taskname is unique

Comment: I have 2 schemas as attached.

Comment: var TaskSchema = new Schema({ taskname: { type: String }, status: { type: String }, duedate: { type: Date }});

var TaskContributorSchema = new Schema({ taskname: { type: String }, name: { type: String }, role: { type: String } });

// taskname is unique